# ERROR: Could not build wheels for pymssql, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, pymssql

I have an issue with installing `pymsql`, any of you had a similar case?

I've found the similar issue to my for M1 user [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70333903/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-pymssql-which-is-required-to-install-pyprojec/70333974)

Also I've try:

Upgrade pip with: python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Upgrade wheel with: pip install --upgrade wheel

Upgrade setuptools with: pip install --upgrade setuptools

When I try install that then I received:

```
Collecting pymssql
  Using cached pymssql-2.2.2.tar.gz (170 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: startedNote: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: pymssql
  Building wheel for pymssql (pyproject.toml): started

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\mikol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\mikol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\mikol\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpli4438o6'
       cwd: C:\Users\mikol\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f4z0veo1\pymssql_f17e29cc25734af0a975be16add0d1d8
  Complete output (23 lines):
  setup.py: platform.system() => Windows
  setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
  setup.py: include_dirs => []
  setup.py: library_dirs => []
  running bdist_wheel
  running build  Building wheel for pymssql (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build pymssql

  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\pymssql
  copying src\pymssql\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\pymssql
  running build_ext
  cythoning src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx to src\pymssql\_mssql.c
  cythoning src\pymssql\_pymssql.pyx to src\pymssql\_pymssql.c
  building 'pymssql._mssql' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src\pymssql
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\mikol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\mikol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc\pymssql\_mssql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src\pymssql\_mssql.obj -DMSDBLIB
  _mssql.c
  src\pymssql\_mssql.c(682): fatal error C1083: Nie moľna otworzy† pliku do\x88Ącz: 'sqlfront.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pymssql
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pymssql, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it'll be appreciated a lot.

Comment: It's weird when I install the pymssql, the pip will download the `.whl` file, and need not build a wheel for pymssql. Could you try to reinstall it without cache? `pip --no-cache-dir install pymssql`

Comment: For a while, I also thought it might be a problem with the Python version and support for 3.10 ...
But you were right, with the use of ``` pip --no-cache-dir install pymssql ``` installed correctly.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar error on macOS (M1 chip) when trying to install `tap-mssql`.  Their documentation [gives instructions](https://github.com/wintersrd/pipelinewise-tap-mssql#additional-os-x-requirements) for resolving the `fatal error: 'sqlfront.h' file not found` on macOS.  After I ran the following I was able to `pip install pymsql` (well, in my case it was `pip install tap-mssql`):

```
brew install freetds
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what I'm about to say is an answer but I do like to chip in to possibly help others who might come across this in future. (I was going to write this in as a comment but I only have 3 rep. point)

My machine is not M1 (It is Intel CPU running Windows 10) and I think many of my environment is different to OP but I did managed to get error which resembles much of what OP got.

I originally went around it by doing 'pip --no-cache-dir install pymssql' too. Which worked well. Graz to @Steven-MSFT

But I stumbled on few more errors (not with pymssql) after that that made me realize I was doing 'pip install -r requirement.txt' on a brand new OS with Python 3.11.1 using the requirement.txt file built by the machine with Python 3.10.4

I didn't realize it would make that much of difference. Apparently it does.
Anyway, basically what I'm trying to say is that reason why module is trying to build wheel for pymssql could possibly be that particular version pymssql you are trying to install may not have been made right for your Python environment.

Reason why I suspected that is because after I uninstalled 3.11.1 and installed 3.10.4 (which is what I should have done in the first place) 'pip install -r requirement.txt' worked like a charm.

So, anyway this is my two cents' worth.

FYI: pymssql version that I had trouble installing was 2.2.5

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and my error was not installing the correct pymysql

The documentation (`https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/installation.html`) says that you should install

`python3 -m pip install PyMySQL`

This worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
```